# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' Error 'MVFloatingButton'

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, tableview, dealloc

I have already done a lot of searching around the net about this issue however I haven't managed to fix it yet, so have had to turn to post this question.

I am using a Floating Button in my app; I have included the library via Cocoapods in my Podfile. The Pod Library is 'MVFloatingButton'. The app was working perfectly fine until I added the Floating Button.

Please find a screenshot of the Floating Button on the TableView (running in iOS Simulator)

[image]

The issue I have is to do with my TableView. The Floating Button displays fine on the tableView however when I navigate back onto the home screen my app crashes with the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7a8a5000 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f91d10>
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f92bf0>
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f93000>
)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x036a1494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0315be02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x036a13bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   Foundation                          0x02d94097 NSKVODeallocate + 353
    4   UIKit                               0x020cf348 -[UIView(UIKitManual) release] + 142
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0316e34f objc_release + 47
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0316f52d _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 371
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x035718a8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x035a943c __CFRunLoopRun + 2364
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x035a8846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x035a865b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x0662a664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0662a4a1 GSEventRun + 104
    13  UIKit                               0x017dfeb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    14  NHSF                                0x00096afa main + 138
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x04865a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This is the code to my .m file:

```
#import "NHSFAdminTeamTableViewController.h"
#import "Admin.h"
#import "UIScrollView+FloatingButton.h"

#define getURLData @"http://dbchudasama.webfactional.com/jsonscriptAdmin.php"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


@interface NHSFAdminTeamTableViewController () <MEVFloatingButtonDelegate>

@end

@implementation NHSFAdminTeamTableViewController

@synthesize jsonArray, AdminArray;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Load data
    [self retrieveData];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //v3.0 -- Initialising Floating Button
    MEVFloatingButton *button = [[MEVFloatingButton alloc] init];
    button.animationType = MEVFloatingButtonAnimationNone;
    button.displayMode = MEVFloatingButtonDisplayModeAlways;
    button.position = MEVFloatingButtonPositionBottomRight;
    button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_create_white_24dp"];
    //button.imageColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    button.outlineColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    button.outlineWidth = 0.0f;
    button.imagePadding = 15.0f;
    button.horizontalOffset = -22.0f;
    button.verticalOffset = -70.0f;
    button.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    button.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
    button.shadowOpacity = 0.6f;
    button.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    button.rounded = YES;
    button.hideWhenScrollToTop = NO;

    [self.tableView setFloatingButtonView:button];
    [self.tableView setFloatingButtonDelegate:self];
    //v3.0 --
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Setting row selection to no for entire table so user can't select an rows. READ ONLY!
    tableView.allowsSelection = NO;

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.AdminArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    // Configure the cell...
    Admin *idObject;

    //Grab the current object in indexPath and set it to Team Coordinator object
    idObject = [AdminArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = idObject.AdminRole;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = idObject.Name;

    //Accessory
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}


/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation
 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */


//Method to retrieve data from database
-(void)retrieveData
{
    //Passing in the URL of the database
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getURLData];

    //Creating object of the database data
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //Set up the TC array
    AdminArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Loop through the jsonArray
    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {

        //Create the Team Coordinator object
        //NSString *eID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *aRole = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"AdminRole"];
        NSString *aName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
        //NSString *eTime = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"eventTime"];
        //NSString *eLocation = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"eventLocation"];

        //Now, add the Team Coordinator object to our TC array
        [AdminArray addObject:[[Admin alloc] initWithAdminTeam:aRole andName:aName]];
    }

    //Reload the table data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//v3.0 -- Delegate Methods for Floating Button 
#pragma mark - MEScrollToTopDelegate Methods

- (void)floatingButton:(UIScrollView *)scrollView didTapButton:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"didTapButton");
    //[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
}

- (void)floatingButtonWillAppear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"floatingButtonWillAppear");
}

- (void)floatingButtonDidAppear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"floatingButtonDidAppear");
}

- (void)floatingButtonWillDisappear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"floatingButtonWillDisappear");
}

- (void)floatingButtonDidDisappear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; {
    NSLog(@"floatingButtonDidDisappear");
}
//v3.0 --

@end
```

From what i understand, I think it has something to do with the **'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'** but I am not 100% sure.

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NHSFAdminTeamTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *AdminArray;


#pragma mark - Class Method
-(void)retrieveData;


//v3,0 -- Delegate Method Constructors for Floating Button
#pragma mark - MEScrollToTopDelegate Methods

- (void)floatingButton:(UIScrollView *)scrollView didTapButton:(UIButton *)button;
- (void)floatingButtonWillAppear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)floatingButtonDidAppear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)floatingButtonWillDisappear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)floatingButtonDidDisappear:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
//3.0 --

@end
```

Any assistance would be of great help! Thanks!